# How to iterate through a pandas dataframe column and check the datatype of each column and change it another datatype if needed

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe "df". I'm trying to access all the columns of the dataframe and check the datatype of each column and if the datatype is "object" i want to change it to float.

I'm trying with the below code, but it is not working:

```
for colname, coltype in df.dtypes.iteritems():
    if coltype == object:
         df[colname] = df[colname].astype(np.float32)
```

I don't understand what is wrong here. Can anyone help me out please ?

Comment: What do you mean, specifically, by "not working"?

Comment: It works for me, not sure what error you're getting

Comment: The column with the datatype object is not getting converted to float @roganjosh

Comment: I want to check the datatype of the column if it is an object or not. So i guess it should be coltype == object  @r.ook

Answer (score 4):

you can try this code

```
types={}
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dtype == object:
        types[col] = float
    else:
        types[col] = df[col].dtype
df = df.astype(types)
```